# Sonatype Nexus: Disable showing of the uploads ip

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I'm using a hosted sonatype nexus for dependency distribution but I want to hide the IP address of my computer from being easily accessible from browsing the repository. How can I disable this being shown? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyqxt.png

Yes, this has been asked before but there was never any reactions about it, And this is still an major thing about this software 
(There are no issues/comments about it in there repo/jira)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.

This is ticketed here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-20956

Comment: I managed to temp fix it by editing the web ui and removing the iPhone. Still there should be a option soon I hope